# How to run two different Main Classes with a Gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I am pretty new to gradle and unfamiliar with the Groovy language/build script syntax etc.

I have one main Class, which starts perfectly fine with

```
gradle run
```

But I now want to create a new Task (uitest), which should be called with something like:

```
gradle -q uitest
```

which should run like above, but with another mainClass.

My build script so far looks like this:

```
plugins {
id 'application'
id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'

}
mainClassName = 'streetsim.ui.StreetSimApp'

javafx {
    version = "11.0.2"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

task uitest(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'streetsim.ui.TemporaryUITestPool.main'
}

group 'groupname'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0'
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

EDIT:
I changed the task as following:

```
task uitest(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'streetsim.ui.TemporaryUITestPool'
}
```

And now I get following error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

As mentioned in the comment to another answer below, I do not want to add VM arguments if possible as I do not want to require a local JavaFX installation

Comment: The [main](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:main) property from `JavaExec` should be the fully qualified name of the class, just like you did for `mainClassName`. So try removing the `.main` part as I assume this is just the method name. If it does not work, please post the error message.

Comment: Just edited my post. @BjørnVester

Answer (score 0):

because this FX below are required you need to add the following to the java command (and remove .main as per comment above)

```
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --module-path <path_to_modules>
```

Comment: Yeah not exactly. I use the javafx-plugin, so I do not need to set a path to local JavaFX Module installations. Though JavaFX runtime components are missing on the task uitest. With normal gradle run it works also without adding those VM args. I want it to work the same way in my own task

Comment: the java fx plugin has the custom task that adds the same - but your task is simple JavaExec - so it can not inherit the custom settings 

you can see the difference if you run   gradle run --debug    and gradle uitest --debug 

you will see the difference --- for run it will show like this 2020-07-02T11:34:37.792+0100 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process  Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --module-path /Users/user/.gradle//javafx-fxml-14-mac.jar:....